# Can't solve indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Can you help me with this, please?

$$\int\sqrt{a\sin(bx)+c} \, dx$$

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This is one of the elliptic integrals: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Int%5BSqrt%5Ba*Sin%5Bb*x%5D%2Bc%5D%2Cx%5D).

Comment: I've tried some substitutions, but I haven't been able to solve it till now.

Comment: Incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind @J.W.Perry

Comment: An elliptic integral of the second kind? - That sounds very special!
Don't know anything about it.^^

Comment: @distressed It is actually quite interesting. Start be reading the wiki on [Elliptic Integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).

Comment: I changed the form, so that my term is now: 
∫sqrt(1+d*(sin(bx))^2)dx

Now it looks more like the given form of an elliptic integral of the second kind than before.
But I'm not sure what I have to do now.

Comment: For your last formulation, the antiderivative is $\frac{E(b x|-d)}{b}$

Answer (score 2):

If $a=c$, or $b=0$, then the integral can be expressed in terms of elementary trigonometric functions, otherwise [elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) must be employed.